# Can mac os X 10.6.6 install on non-apple hardware?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

Hi im new to iphone development by searching i found that iphone development can only be done on mac os and i also found that the latest version of iphone sdk only run on Intel mac os x 10.6.6 or later. i have some question regarding this ,

Can i install mac os x 10.6.6 on same hardware on which i currently install windows xp?
Configuration of my pc is :

inter pentium 4 2.4 ghz, 2.5 gb ram and 140 gb hd.

2 . or if not can i do iphone development on my window xp by running mac os x 10.6.6 on VMware?

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://lifehacker.com/5672051/how-to-build-a-hackintosh-mac-and-install-os-x-in-eight-easy-steps

Answer (score 2):

Search the web for Hackintosh.

But you have to know that this is considered illegal by Apple. You can only use MacOS on their hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It does, but does not perform well. Not all features will be working. It might be very slow in performance.

Look here for the hardward supported [Link](http://www.hackintosh.com/#hackintosh_compatible)